# How do I solve AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'empty'?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to perform a sensitivity analysis for a system of 10 differential equations and 38 parameters, with the following code:

```py
# Formulating the problem for sensitivity analysis
problem = {
    'num_vars': num_vars,
    'names': p_names,
    'bounds': bounds
}

# Generate the parameter samples using Saltelli's sampling method
num_samples = 256 # number of samples

param_values = saltelli.sample(problem, num_samples, calc_second_order=False)


# Run the model for each parameter sample
results = numpy.empty([param_values.shape[0], 10])
```

and I keep getting a this message error:

```py
results = np.empty([param_values.shape[0], 10])
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'empty'
```

I have followed some solutions in discussion forums like, trying to format param_values as a float, `np.float64` or different kinds of array or lists. Also, I have tried to use different functions, for example, instead of using `np.empty`, used `np.zeros` or `np.ones`. I also tried downgrading numpy to a previous version, but it did not work. I am using python 3.11 and numpy 1.24.3.
I could not find a build-in plain function in python to substitute `np.empty`.

Comment: Do you have `numpy.empty` or `np.empty`? It seems like you are assigning something to `np` somewhere in your code

Comment: Have you actually verified that the `results` variable is actually not being populated anywhere else?
Furthermore, this is being caused since your `results` holds a `numpy.float64` type object, but what you actually want to specify is the shape of the array (which needs to be an int or a tuple of int)

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, it seems `np` is being modified somewhere. You should post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of flopping around trying all sorts of wild guesses, read the error message - all of it.

If you were using some function that isn't part of `numpy` you'd get a message like

```
 AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'foobar'
```

you got

```
 AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'empty'
```

That means that in `np.empty(...)`, `np` is not the numpy `module`, but is instead a `numpy` float object, an element of an array.

`AttributeError` is often the result of mistaken identity of the variable on the left side.  It could be a problem with the right side, if you made a typo or made a bad guess, but more often the left side has been assigned to something unexpected.  Often that LHS is something like `None`.  The problem may be worse in Jupyter notebooks, where previously run cells can leave garbage like this.

So in this case track down any assignments to `np` or `numpy`.

AttributeError like this comes up often enough that it almost qualifies as a `close` reason.